# IllegalArgumentException injection dependencies into Android Service

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, dagger-2

I'm trying to inject dependencies into a subclass of `FirebaseInstanceIdService`, but I'm getting a compile time exception that is very vague.

**EDIT**: When I comment out the inject method declaration, it compiles.

AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, ApiModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

  fun inject(app: MyApplication)

  fun plus(someModule: SomeModule): SomeComponent
  /* omitting others for sake of brevity */

  //If I comment this one out, the project compiles and runs
  fun plus(firebaseInstanceModule: FirebaseInstanceModule): FirebaseInstanceComponent     
}
```

Module:

```
@Module
class FirebaseInstanceModule {

  @Provides
  fun providePresenter(userService: UserService): PushPresenter =
      PushPresenterImpl(userService)

}
```

Component:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = [(FirebaseInstanceModule::class)])
interface FirebaseInstanceComponent {

  //Commenting out this method, the project compiles
  fun inject(service: MyFirebaseInstanceIdService)

}
```

Service:

```
class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService : FirebaseInstanceIdService() {

  private val TAG = "FirebaseInstanceId"

  @Inject
  lateinit var pushPresenter: PushPresenter

  override fun onCreate() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")
    mainApplication.appComponent.plus(FirebaseInstanceModule()).inject(this)
  }

  override fun onTokenRefresh() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onTokenRefresh")
    val token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().token

    token?.let { pushPresenter.updateToken(it) }
  }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:158)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:892)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:919)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:891)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:385)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor91.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.writer.ClassName.peerNamed(ClassName.java:130)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.SourceFiles.membersInjectorNameForMembersInjectionBinding(SourceFiles.java:266)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.InjectBindingRegistry.registerBinding(InjectBindingRegistry.java:199)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.InjectBindingRegistry.getOrFindMembersInjectionBinding(InjectBindingRegistry.java:261)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingGraph$Factory$RequestResolver.rollUpMembersInjectionBindings(BindingGraph.java:374)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingGraph$Factory$RequestResolver.rollUpMembersInjectionBindings(BindingGraph.java:378)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingGraph$Factory$RequestResolver.lookUpBindings(BindingGraph.java:366)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingGraph$Factory$RequestResolver.resolve(BindingGraph.java:461)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingGraph$Factory$RequestResolver.resolve(BindingGraph.java:464)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingGraph$Factory.create(BindingGraph.java:228)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingGraph$Factory.create(BindingGraph.java:236)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingGraph$Factory.create(BindingGraph.java:151)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessingStep.process(ComponentProcessingStep.java:76)
    at dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:228)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:205)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:166)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:106)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:83)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:376)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:367)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:132)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: Seems like a Dagger error when processing your source code. Could you check your Gradle Log to see if there is another error message generated by Dagger?

Comment: If that is actually an android service, you should call `super.onCreate()` as well after injecting. (probably not your error though)